# My timer (scheduleAtFixedRate) doesnt loop

Tags: java, image, animation, timer, keylistener

In the following programm I tried to repeatedly swap two images, to create a walking effect. To achieve that, I created a timer in which the source of img3 is getting changed alternately between Bob1 and Bob2. This works fine. However I of course want the animation to pause when you stop moving. So I put an if - statement in the run method. This also works, if I use a variable, which isn´t changed. But if I use the moveleft variable (which is true, if d is beeing pressed and false if it isn´t), i´t changes the image only the moment I press or the moment I release the key, not if I hold it down. Below are the relevant classes.

```
package pack1;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyHandler implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {

            Var.moveleft = true;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {

            Var.moveleft = false;

        }

    }

}
```

and

```
package pack1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Animation {

    Timer timer;

    public Animation() {

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (Var.moveleft == true) {

                    if (Var.bobImg == false) {

                        try {

                            Var.img3 = ImageIO.read(new File("rsc/Bob2.png"));

                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                        Var.bobImg = true;

                    } else if (Var.bobImg == true) {

                        try {

                            Var.img3 = ImageIO.read(new File("rsc/Bob1.png"));

                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                        Var.bobImg = false;

                    }

                }

            }

        }, 0, 100);

    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, don’t use java.util.Timer, use a Swing Timer, apart from be simpler to use it doesn’t violate single threaded nature of Swing

Comment: Looks like you're accessing the same variables on different threads.  You can only do this if you specifically handle the concurrency with synchronized blocks and/or volatile variables as needed.  The simpler solution is to use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html), which is always called from the Event Dispatch Thread.  This way there is no concurrency, i.e. no two things are being done at the same time.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok, but a swing Timer seems to work a bit differently. Could you maybe give a short example, so I can properly implement it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837804/rendering-with-a-timer-and-paintcomponent-is-causing-no-rendering-to-happen/57837997?r=SearchResults#57837997

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ideed using a swing timer works out perfectly with something like this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Animation {

public Animation() {
        
        Timer timer;

        timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        if (Var.bobImg == true) {

                            try {

                                Var.img3 = ImageIO.read(new File("rsc/Bob1.png"));

                            } catch (IOException e1) {

                                e1.printStackTrace();

                            }

                            Var.bobImg = false;

                        } else if (Var.bobImg == false) {

                            try {
                                
                                Var.img3 = ImageIO.read(new File("rsc/Bob2.png"));

                            } catch (IOException e1) {

                                e1.printStackTrace();

                            }

                            Var.bobImg = true;

                        }

                    Var.lbl4.repaint();

            }

        });

    }

}
```